# Rails, syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, syntax, scope

I'm following this tutorial to create a messaging system in rails. 
https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1#.lhwzqr92b

My main issue now is that I'm getting a syntax error `unexpected '?'` related to the following scope validation in my Conversation model:

```
  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
  where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ? ) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ? )", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
```

It's supposed to check if a conversation between two users already exists so we can make sure only a conversation exists between 2 users.

I've been trying fiddling with the code taking out some parenthesis and googling only gives me general answers. I'm going crazy here. Could someone help to point out the syntax error?

Comment: Your `“`looks strange. Did you copy and paste this line? It should look like this `"`

Comment: thanks jack I think there was a problem with those quotes indeed. It's not raising the syntax error anymore but the quotes are highlighting the code in a funny way. i'll see if it works

Comment: Sorry Jack this shouldn't have happened is working now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the copy/pasted quotation marks `“` -> `"`.
When following tutorials, we should take extra care when copying code into our projects where quotes are used.

Thank @slowjack2k for that answer.